# Exit all threads in case of Error in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm working on a python project were I want the same behavior as in `C` for my threads. In `C` when the main thread exit, it kills all other threads.

The project contains a `TCP` error server that it used to get logs from other threads and other software .The `TCP` link is simplex.
Some errors must involve the end of the whole program.

- For external software I can kill them using their `PID`.
- For other threads I've tried `sys._exit()`, sometimes it works, and sometimes some threads remain.

If my other threads were looping I could use a `semaphore` or something like that, but it is only one iteration of a linear process.

I've thought about the design pattern `Producer/Consumer` or add a lot of `lock.acquire()/lock.release()` but I think it will add more complexity and it imply to break the linear thread.

I've had a look to other `Stackoverflow` question I've found those solutions:

- Use `sys._exit()` but its success rate is not 100%.
- Convert my threads into `subprocess` to kill them easily, but in my case I can't.

I'm looking for a solution, a design pattern or something else to solve it.

PS: I'm a `C` lover and each time I deal with Python I think to solutions as simple as to call `exit()` to kill all my threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your worker threads daemon threads, they will die when all your non-daemon threads (e.g. the main thread) have exited.

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon

Thread daemon status `isDaemon()` is `False`, set it `True` by `setDaemon(True)`

*Another solution :*

To make the thread stop on Keyboard Interrupt signal (ctrl+c) you can catch the exception "KeyboardInterrup" and cleanup before exiting. Like this:

```
try:
    start_thread() #And the rest of your main  
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    cleanup_stop_thread();
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: I've tried to set my threads as daemonics but it's seems it don't work or it wait for a resource to be freed but I don't know which one.

Comment: It should work, anyway, you could create a stop_method for your thread and in you main, add a `try .. except` to catch keyboard interuption and call your `stop_thread` method.

Comment: It sound great I will try it.

Comment: I think you have another hidden issue. Those two solutions really should work. If you keep your threads in a structure you could call the `stop` method. Why do you say that you can't send signals between threads ?

Comment: I've done some tests, The try/except solution don't work because a can't send a signals between threads. But the daemonic solution may works, I've got a main thread that runs 'ThreadA' and 'ThreadB', 'ThreadC' is created and launched by the 'ThreadB', The three thread are created as daemonic thread but when I try to exit the 'ThreadC' remains.